# actions are dispatching every time i render a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react and kind of experimenting with the hooks and i am stuck in a problem where i am using useEffect to dispatch an action to redux store. so everything works fine but the problem i am facing is every time i render a child component in my main component it dispatch the action. Like there are cards that are basically child components and whenever i click on of them to show more details it dispatch the actions that are in parent components same if i close the component so my question how can i prevent that from happening and only render the items once. Let me know if you need any other code..

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
//ANIMATION AND STYLED
import styled from "styled-components";
import { motion, AnimatePresence, AnimateSharedLayout } from "framer-motion";

//REDUX and ROUTER
import {
  AllPopularGame,
  NextPage,
  PrevPage,
} from "../Actions/popularGameActions";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
//COMPONENTS
import Game from "./games";
import GameDetail from "./gameDetail";

const PopularGames = () => {
  //GETTNG PATH
  const Location = useLocation();
  const History = useHistory();
  const pathId = Location.pathname.split("/")[4];

  //Redux store
  const { allPopularGame, gameCount, currentPage, gameLoading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.popular
  );
  //No of pages
  const totalPage = Math.ceil(gameCount / 36);

  //SCROLL TO TOP
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [currentPage]);

  //Handlers
  const PrevHandler = () => {
    if (currentPage <= 1) {
      return;
    } else {
      dispatch(PrevPage());
      History.push(`/popular/games?page=${currentPage - 1}`);
    }
  };

  const NextHandler = () => {
    if (currentPage >= totalPage) {
      console.log("Hello");
      return;
    } else {
      dispatch(NextPage());
      History.push(`/popular/games?page=${currentPage + 1}`);
    }
  };
  //Fetch all popular games
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchGames(page) {
      const games = dispatch(AllPopularGame(page));
      return games;
    }
    fetchGames(currentPage);
  }, [dispatch, currentPage]);

  // {`${currentPage} /popular/games/${popularGames.id}`}
  return (
    <Popular>
      <h2>Popular Games </h2>
      <AnimateSharedLayout type="crossfade">
        <AnimatePresence>
          {pathId && <GameDetail pathId={pathId} curPage={currentPage} />} //child component
        </AnimatePresence>
        {gameLoading ? (
          <h2>Loading</h2>
        ) : (
          <Games>
            {allPopularGame.map((popularGames) => (
              <Link
                to={`/popular/games/${currentPage}/${popularGames.id}`}
                key={popularGames.id}
              >
                <Game
                  name={popularGames.name}
                  img={popularGames.background_image}
                  rating={popularGames.rating}
                  id={popularGames.id}
                  key={popularGames.id}
                  released={popularGames.released}
                />
              </Link>
            ))}
          </Games>
        )}
      </AnimateSharedLayout>
      <Page>
        <Button onClick={PrevHandler}>
          <span>Prev</span>
        </Button>
        <p>{currentPage}</p>
        <Button onClick={NextHandler}>
          <span>Next</span>
        </Button>
      </Page>
    </Popular>
  );
};
```

**Github repo**
[Current code](https://github.com/Callmeizaz/GamerHub.git)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing the repository! It's quite clear now. You're using a link and re-routing the page - so although the components are the same and there isn't a re-paint on the UI, the entire page still mounts again. That's why your useEffect gets triggered everytime you click on a card (and even when you close one!).

Your UI state is managed by the path in the URL - this is really bad practice - especially considering that you aren't making any API calls to fetch data based on the URL.

Here's what I would suggest -

1. Replace the pathID variable that you are currently reading from the URL with a useState hook:

   `const [activeGameID, setActiveGameID]=useState(null);`
2. Replace the Link component that you use to wrap the Game with a regular div and pass it an onClick handler to setActiveGameID:

   ````js
   <Games>  
       {popular.map((popularGames) => (  
           <div
               onClick={() => setActiveGameID(popularGames.id)}  
               key={popularGames.id}  
           >  
               <Game
                   name={popularGames.name}
                   img={popularGames.background_image}
                   rating={popularGames.rating}
                   id={popularGames.id}
                   key={popularGames.id}
                   released={popularGames.released}
               />
           </div>
       ))}
   </Games>```
   ````

I think the problem you may be facing is that your animations are dependent on URL changes - in that case I would urge you to use some other way to animate your cards.

Comment: Added link to my repo